# hr tag cross-browsing

Tags: html, css

I have this css styling for hr element:

```
hr#content {
background: url("linie-content.png") no-repeat center bottom transparent;
border: none !important;
position: relative;
top: 272px;
           }
```

In Firefox is showing , but in Chrome doesn't work ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works for me but you need to add height to see the image.